# Masking 2d arrays using boolean array

Tags: python, arrays, knn

I am trying to implement kfold validation in python for the CIFAR-10 training set so for that i am trying to mask the the training set using a boolean list

X_Train_folds is an array of shape 5X1000X3072

```
selection = [True, True, True, True, True]
for k in k_choices:
    for i in xrange(0,num_folds):
        selection[i] = False

        classifier = KNearestNeighbor()
        classifier.train(X_train_folds[selection,:].reshape(1,X_train_folds.shape[0]*X_train_folds.shape[1])), 
                        Y_train_folds[selection,:].reshape(1,Y_train_folds.shape[0]*Y_train_folds.shape[1]))
        dists = classifier.compute_distances_no_loops(X_train_folds[i])
        y_pred = classifier.predict_labels(dists, k)
        num_correct = np.sum(y_pred == Y_train_folds[i])
        accuracy = float(num_correct) / (y_train.shape[0]/num_folds)
        k_to_accuracies[k] = accuracy




   TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

EDIT 1: The problem could be understood as i am trying to get like 4 rows except the ith one in the loop like if the array is [1,2,3,4,5] first i want a list of [2,3,4,5] then [1,3,4,5] and so on

Comment: The problem is Python doesn't have a true 2D array structure -- you could fake it using a dictionary instead of a list, or you could use something like numpy which has 2D arrays that use that syntax.

Comment: i did not understand your second solution could you elaborate? and also you're talking about making the X_Train_folds as a dictionary? i think the dictionary one is a really good suggestion i will surely try it but i would like if you could elaborate on the second one as it seems more normal

Comment: Maybe you could explain the problem you're trying to solve? It seems like you want to get 1 row, then 2 rows, etc. using the boolean array but I'm really not sure.

Comment: no i am trying to get like 4 rows except the ith one in the loop like if the array is [1,2,3,4,5] first i want a list of [2,3,4,5] then [1,3,4,5] and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just successively drop each i_th item in a list?

```
mask_this = [1,2,3,4,5]

[mask_this[:i]+mask_this[(i+1):] for i in range(len(mask_this))]  

Out[17]: [[2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```